# Dynamic bayesian network inference: weaken the evidence in the past

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network

For the inference in a dynamic bayesian network (DBN), forward and backward algorithm can be applied:
$P(X_k | o_{1:t}) \propto P(o_{k+1:t}|X_k) P(X_k|o_{1:k})$. By using this method, observation from time $1:k$ can be discarded, the posterior distribution $P(X_k|o_{1:k})$ after time $k$ is used as a prior to estimate $P(X_k | o_{1:t})$. In some manner, all the historical observations are updated in $P(X_k|o_{1:k})$.

Is there an efficient algorithm for DBN inference use a partial or most recent observations ($o_{k-s+1:k}$, observations from $k-s+1$ to $k$ are considered to be most recent) to estimate the current state of $X$?